# Sphinx autosummary, include and base classes

Tags: python, inheritance, include, python-sphinx, summary

I feel like I've tried everything to create autosummary tables with working links in a maintainable workflow when documenting inherited class attributes. I could really use a tip.

I thought something like this would be nice...

base.py:

```
"""
.. -- include below --
.. autosumary::

    BaseFoo.a
    BaseFoo.b

.. -- include above --
"""
class BaseFoo(object):
    @property
    def a(self): pass

    @property
    def b(self): pass
```

foo.py:

```
"""
Inherited from :class:`base.BaseFoo` ...

.. include:: base.py
    :start-after: --- include below ---
    :end-before: --- include above ---
"""
class Foo(BaseFoo):
    pass
```

The problem is Sphinx won't create the links in the autosummary table because the class names don't match. It doesn't seem to understand inheritance even with automodule     inherited-members in use (The inherited members are auto-documented, it is just that the table links don't work).

I tried to use the replace directive, which would have been a nice way to go, but autosummary failed to generate anything.

I tried using just the attribute with a leading `.` (e.g. `.a`), thinking perhaps the auto-completion might kick in.

Autosummary seems like such a manual bottleneck in the system. There must be a better way.

Any ideas?

P.S. Can someone with over 1500 add a tag for autosummary or sphinx-autosummary or whatever makes sense?